# Error while opening large account

Tags: account, query

Here i got one error while processing on accounts.

i can't open large accounts and got the below error.

[image]

So what can i do to open that accounts i mean is there any way to resolve this error and proceed further.

can i need to purge anything to avoid this kind of errors.

Thanks your support in advanced....

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say whats going on.  Your SF pod might just be running slow (worth checking trust.salesforce.com).

If the problem persists your best bet would be to open a case with salesforce support.

You might try creating a bare bones page layout and seeing if you can get it to load.

Comment: It appears "data related", suggesting it's just this one account. Salesforce.com *should* be notified so they can fix it.

Comment: but this was happened 2 or 3 times within a week....

Comment: @Vivek113 was it always the same account?  Or was it happening to multiple ones?  Do you have any VF pages inline on the layout?

Comment: No it was happened with multiple accounts and also it's standard account page layout.....

Comment: Unfortunately I think SF support are the only ones that can help you with this one....

Comment: Hello sir still now i got the same error with some rare account records only for some times....when i refresh 2 or 3 times it's gone....please help....